# Elementary linear algebra sources

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I took matrix computations course, our course book is [Numerical Linear Algebra and Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201126494). As a computer science student, sometimes I get the impression that I lack some fundamental background knowledge about it. It'd be great if you could introduce some useful but not very long elementary linear algebra sources (not very long, since I should get back to my course book ASAP).

Please note that I've Googled the subject and got some cookbooks but I am looking for some sources which are specifically related to the above mentioned book and covers those topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Gilbert Strang is a very approachable book that has a lot of useful examples. It introduces the fundamentals very concretely and transitions smoothly into a few of the more abstract ideas that are needed in linear algebra, so you get a pretty complete understanding of the subject.

This book also has the benefit that you can follow his lectures (which are based on the book) online through MIT Open CourseWare [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/).

Answer (score 3):

I used the following book as a reference even in my grad studies. I really think you could understand the material presented in it even if you begin reading from the middle. :)

- [Elementary Linear
  Algebra](http://www.amazon.ca/Elementary-Linear-Algebra-Howard-Anton/dp/0470458216)

Comment: To add some more to the answer, I also found http://linear.axler.net quite useful in certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

In fact a lot of books can be recommend :

Usually the best book for starting linear algebra (for mathematics students) is

Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze

([http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Edition-Kenneth-Hoffman/dp/0135367972](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135367972))

You can have a look at it if its good for you.

But going by your background you would be more interested in Matrix Analysis for which :

Matrix Theory by David W. Lewis

(http://books.google.nl/books?id=vmztIjDJpu0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

is better.

And also while browsing the internet I found a book with all the apt content that would be required for you :

Matrix Analysis and Applied linear algebra by Carl D. Meyer (chapters are available for download with permission)

I hope you would not need anything outside these three books for Linear Algebra background. Check these in the reverse order : Carl D. Meyer, Lewis and lastly Hoffman and Kunze.

All the best ! :)

*My personal favourite is "Linear Algebra : A geometric approach by S.Kumaresan" short and sweet. But I do not know if you can get it outside India. Probably a check in the library would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found "Linear Algebra (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics)" by Larry Smith to be the perfect start in the theory of Linear Algebra right after the basics.

The prerequisites are: you know the basic mechanics and operations as well as the definition of Vector Space and Linear Transformation.

It has plenty of **examples that apply the theory** and you can work through the first half fairly **quickly** and pick and choose what you want to learn after that! (Like Spectral Theorem, Jordan Canonical Form, and Inner Product Spaces might be a bit much for what you're going for)